# Do I need to prove this?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, provable-security, pairings, abe

I am using ABE scheme that has already proven under BDHE assumption. Here is the scheme https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/290.pdf

In the key generation algorithm, I want to tie the user secret key components with a message $m∈GT$. $m$ is different from the one used in the encryption algorithm.
I did like this

$S=M.e(g^t, g^d) = M.e(g,g)^{td}$  where $t,d∈Z$ are randomly chosen.
$t$ is used to tie all other secret key components together.

$S$ will be given to the user along with the secret key which have these components $(K=g^bg^{at}, L=g^t, h1^t, h2^t, …)$

$d $ and $g^d$ will be kept secure with the authority.

My question, do I need to re-prove the security of the scheme considering $S$

Comment: What do you want that tieing to achieve? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer thank you, I want to ensure that (1) it hard to distinguish the term $e(g,g)^{td}$? given the secret key including $S$, and (2) the user cannot exchange (collude) $S$ with other user's $S'$

Comment: "hard to distinguish the term $e(g,g)^{td}$" from what? ​ What does your property (2) mean? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer (1) distinguish from a random value; the second property is about whether or not the scheme will be resisted against collusion between users

Comment: How is $t$ generated for (1)? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer $t$ is selected randomly from $Z$ and embeded into the secret key compnents. $t$ is generated for one secret key, therefore other secret keys will have different randoms (not equal to $t$).

Comment: Is $t$ from the paper you linked to, or a part you came up with? ​ In any case, does "just have the personal private keys include an authenticated encryption of the ordered pair [m,underlying_scheme's_personal_private_key]" work? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer yes it is from the paper, yes that is the question, does this work? Or i need to have some sort of proof

Comment: Well, that goes back to the question of what the "tieing" is supposed to achieve. ​ My previous comment's approach would let the Master Key Holder verify alleged [m,personal_private_key] pairs and recover their m, since the authenticryption key is not used for anything other than that, so the rest of the interaction can be simulated to mount an attack on the authenticryption scheme. ​ (continued ...) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (... continued) ​ However, with that approach, the adversary can still trivially output a decryption circuit C such that [[applying C always gives the same result as honest decryption with their personal private key] and [absolutely nothing about m can be deduced from C]]. ​ (C is just "run the inner scheme's decryption with the inner scheme's personal private key" - That does not involve the the authenticryption of m at all.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Rickydemer excellent explanation, now I am writing a paper. How can I prove the hardness of $S$?  Is it DL problem in the sense that it is hard to distinguish $d$ from a random value.

Comment: Should "$S$" be replaced with "finding $S$" or "distinguishing $S$ from uniform" or something else? ​ The DL problem is not about distinguishing, so I don't understand your last sentence. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Rickydemer what I meant is that given $S$ to the user, it is hard to find $m$ If you don't know the term $d$. Clearly the user needs to guess the term $d$ which is believed to be a DL problem

Answer (score 8):

I purposefully did not look at the details of the change you are proposing because whatever the change is, the answer is a resounding YES. If you make *any* change to a cryptographic construction, then you **must prove the security of the modified scheme**. If you are lucky, you may be able to reduce the security of the modified scheme to the original scheme, or you may be able to reuse a lot of the intermediate claims of the proof of the original scheme. However, you must prove!